# how to get filenames from folder in C++

Tags: c++, file

suppose I want to write ls or dir. how do I get the list of files in a given directory?
something equivalent of .NET's Directory.GetFiles, and additional information.

not sure about the string syntax, but:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: Agree - would close if SO allowed me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the FindFirstFile and FindNextFile APIs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx

Comment: I looked for quite some time for this functions in MSDN, however I found stuff like solution in .NET, J++, JavaScript and practically everything else but it. thank :)

Answer (score 23):

Check out [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), an portable and excellent library.

**Edit**: An example from the library:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string p(argc <= 1 ? "." : argv[1]);

  if (is_directory(p))
  {
     for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr!=directory_iterator(); ++itr)
     {
       cout << itr->path().filename() << ' '; // display filename only
       if (is_regular_file(itr->status())) cout << " [" << file_size(itr->path()) << ']';
       cout << '\n';
      }
  }
  else cout << (exists(p) : "Found: " : "Not found: ") << p << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish I knew BOOST better, I installed it on Windows but I got stuck when I tried to use it from VS. Much cleaner than that ugly winAPI.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:
[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx), and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx) can be used to list files in a specified directory.

Pseudo code:

```
 Find the first file in the directory.
 do
   { 
   //

   }while(NextFile);

Close
```

Answer (score 0):

[Poco::DirectoryIterator](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryIterator.html) is an alternative

Answer (score -3):

This is totally platform depeanded.
If on windows you should use WINAPI as suggested.